# Volatility surface

Tags: options, volatility, heston, calibration

When fitting/calibrating a option model like heston to option data, what are some useful data handling to do?
The basic thing is to remove all options with no trade/volume, but how many maturities should one use and how far ITM/OTM?
I can't really find any scientific articles on above, but would appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This reference may help you: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4208856

You can get a good hint on what's the idea of the whole thing by just reading the first two/three sections.